# Losing data with http get (RC1 and TS)

Tags: http, typescript, angular

I'm losing data when doing http request from backend. I tried to make a plunker to showcase my problem, but I didn't get it to work, some problem with the configuration? Here it is though, with only the neccessary code to showcase my problem: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IlVmGxWa4wxMbKL72wh7?p=preview)

Well, I have tried to showcase my problem with local Json, but in reality I have an actual backend. The trouble lies in the service when retrieving a single hero. That is where I lose data.

Part of `Hero` class:

```
export class Hero {

  private powers: Array<Power>;

  constructor(public id: string, public name: string) {
    this.powers = new Array<Power>();
  }
}
```

Example of Json of one hero:

```
{
  "id":"randomString",
  "name":"heroName",
  "powers":[
    {
      "text":"power",
      "value":"1"
    }
  ]
}
```

When doing the `getById` method I need to assign the incoming data as a new hero, that then leaves out the array `powers`, as it is private in the `Hero` class and I can only assign the id and name of the hero:

```
  public getById(id: string) {
    return this.http.get('/app/hero.json')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      //without following line it gives self.context error:
      .map(res => new Hero(res.id, res.name))
  }
```

So I am losing the powers Array and all the data in the Array, as it creates a new Powers array each time I retrieve a single hero. Naturally I want all the data that is in the Hero object!

So in this example app I have ignored using id, and just returning a hero. I noticed when printing to the console that in this example the `powers` array is ignored completely, but in my actual app it creates a new Array! And btw, in my actual app my method looks like this:

```
getById(id: string) {
    return this.http.get('someURL' + id)
        //.map((res: Response) => {console.log('res', res);}); // <--- logs correct data including powers that is populated with data!
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        //unless this following line is added, it gives error "self.context...", BUT I lose data!

        .map(hero => new hero(hero.id, hero.name));
}
```

I have tried to filter the Hero, but it doesn't work!

```
  //undefined
  getById(id: string){
    return this.http.get('/app/heroes.json')
    .map(heroes => this.heroes.filter(hero => hero.id === id)[0]);
  }
```

So I am really at a loss of how to move forward, how to get the data that is stored in the powers array, and not only the name and id of the hero.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: updated my question a bit, where hopefully my problem is clearer. So I need that the data in the powers array is included when I retrieve one hero. Now I lose all the data in the powers array as I need to create a new Hero when retrieving a single hero. And there I can only assign the id and name of the hero. powers array becomes empty, even though I have data there.

Comment: Why can't you just pass in the array as another parameter? Or better yet, since you know the structure, just pass in an object literal representing the hero.

Comment: @cdbajorin Could you help me a bit with what you suggested. I'm a total newbie. I know the structure yes, and I could pass in an object literal representing the hero. That sounds like a great idea actually, but I have no clue as how to do that. I've tried all kinds of things to include the powers array, but I always get a compile error that the powers is private in hero class. So obviously I'm doing it wrong and have no clue to as how I'm supposed to do that ;)

Comment: I'll write up an answer. Can you edit in the little snippet where you declare the Hero class along with the JSON of a hero? It will make the answer more meaningful.

Comment: I really appreciate the help! I added the class and Json in my question just now.

Comment: I did it differently than our discussion. The reason mainly being that it would be a minimal and non-breaking change, compared to remaking the constructor to take a completely different parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Hero class takes two parameters, the `id` and the `name`. Since you're only passing in those two parameters, the array of `powers` on your JSON never gets used.
You can add an optional `powers` parameter:

```
class Hero {

    constructor(public id: string, 
                public name: string, 
                private powers: Power[] = []) {}
}
```

Note the syntax: `private powers: Power[] = []`. This makes `powers` an optional parameter with a default value of an empty array. This does exactly what you are doing with `this.powers = new Array<Power>();`, except it will allow you to pass in an array of powers if they already exist.

Looking in your plunkr, the only problem with this is that you've declared `Power` as a class, which means you'll have to call `new Power()` on each of the items in the `powers` array on your JSON before passing them into the constructor. If the powers themselves don't actually have class methods, you could change it to an interface to preserve the types while making the instantiation a bit easier:

```
interface Power {
    text: string;
    value: string;
}
```

In your `getById` function, you would just need to add the powers argument:

```
  public getById(id: string) {
    return this.http.get('/app/hero.json')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .map(res => new Hero(res.id, res.name, res.powers))
  }
```

If you do need `Power` as a class, another option is to add a static method to the `Hero` class that is used specifically for your server response:

```
class Hero {

    constructor(public id: string,
                public name: string,
                private powers: Power[] = []) {}


    static initFromJSON(json): Hero {

        let id = json.id;
        let name = json.name;
        let powers: Power[] = json.powers.map(power => new Power(power.text, power.value));
        return new Hero(id, name, powers);
    }
}
```

You could then have your `getById` function as:

```
public getById(id: string) {
    return this.http.get('/app/hero.json')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .map(res => Hero.initFromJSON(res))
}
```

Comment: Power does in reality contain methods and another Array of Objects itself and so forth, so one hero is a nested mess :D But your answer is very good, and well explained! I can now see in the console that the correct data is passed, even though the code breaks after that. Thank you for taking your time to answer, helped a lot, and now am one step closer to getting this app to work!

Comment: I updated with another approach that might fit your situation.

Comment: big thumbs up!! Well, apparently I was once on the right track during these days when I have banged my head against the wall with this. I tried a similar approach earlier, but I just didn't get the syntax right! Now I see all the data that I have provided for this example! In reality I have much more nested data inside Power and have tried to display that all morning, but no luck yet. This has answered my question though, more than well! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works as a charm, but have been playing around with my code and I also came up with the following. So this is an alternative solution if the Array `Power` is private in the `Hero` class.

No need for changes in the class, so it stays the same:

```
export class Hero {

  private powers: Array<Power>;

  constructor(public id: string, public name: string) {
    this.powers = new Array<Power>();
  }
}
```

`getById` method the same build as the second one in the answer above:

```
public getById(id: string) {
    return this.http.get('/app/hero.json')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .map(res => Hero.heroFromJSON(res))
}
```

Add this static method to `Hero` class:

```
static heroFromJSON(json) {
    let hero = Object.create(Hero.prototype);
    return Object.assign(hero, json, { powers: new Array<Power>(json.powers) })
}
```